# Merge 2 files based on all available values of the first column in both files

Tags: files, merge

I need to merge below 2 files:

- **file1**:

  ```
  viewer  23
  test    27
  remark  2
  ```
- **file2**:

  ```
  viewer  2990
  exam    200
  remark  240
  ```

**merged file should be as shown below:**

```
type    value1  value2  difference
viewer  23      2990       -2967
test    27        0          27
remark  2        240        -238
exam    0        200        -200
```

Comment: I removed the blank lines from your files, if they are actually part of the original file, please let me know and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'x' file:

```
FNR==1 {
    ++FILENO
}
{
    T[$1]++
    X[$1,FILENO]=$2
}
END {
    print "type\tvalue1\tvalue2\tdifference"
    for(t in T)
        print t"\t"X[t,1]+0"\t"X[t,2]+0"\t"0+X[t,1]-X[t,2]
}
```

The run:

```
$ awk -f x file1 file2
type    value1  value2  difference
viewer  23      2990    -2967
remark  2       240     -238
test    27      0       27
exam    0       200     -200
```

---

Version with line for "total", sorting and skipping lines without difference:

```
FNR==1 {
    ++FILENO
}
{
    T[$1]++
    X[$1,FILENO]=$2
}
END {
    print "type\tvalue1\tvalue2\tdifference"
    for(t in T) {
        if(X[t,1]!=X[t,2])
            print t"\t"X[t,1]+0"\t"X[t,2]+0"\t"0+X[t,1]-X[t,2] | "sort"
        S[1]+=X[t,1]
        S[2]+=X[t,2]
    }
    close("sort")
    print "total\t"S[1]+0"\t"S[2]+0"\t"S[1]-S[2]+0
}
```

I added a line "yawns  3" to both input files...

file1:

```
yawns   3
viewer  23
test    27
remark  2
```

file2:

```
viewer  2990
yawns   3
exam    200
remark  240
```

Running:

```
$ awk -f x file1 file2
type    value1  value2  difference
exam    0       200     -200
remark  2       240     -238
test    27      0       27
viewer  23      2990    -2967
total   55      3433    -3378
```

...and "yawns" does not show in the output.

GAWK can sort without external `sort`, but as long as possible, I prefer not to unse GAWKy features.

Comment: hi yeti, I got below errors when launching your command. awk: syntax error near line 6
awk: illegal statement near line 6
awk: syntax error near line 11
awk: illegal statement near line 11

Comment: I took exactly the code from here using cut'n'paste to verify it again and it runs on my system without any errors.

Comment: I should be using a Linux machine?

Comment: I tried this on linux. Nevertheless I do not see why AWK on other systems should behave different.

Comment: It worked perfectly on Linux. Do you know how I can fix it on SunOS?

Comment: I tried to find manpages about `awk` in SunOS... SunOS-5.10's `awk` seems not have SUBSEP, so X[a,b] may be the problem. This is sooooo ancient, I couldn't believe it! I found a reference to `nawk` at the end of the `awk` manpage. `nawk` is a newer version of awk having this feature. Please check for `nawk` being avaiable in your SunOS or for a way to install it and then forget the ancient other `awk` version. If all else fails, it is possible to write this without using 2-dimensional arrays but getting a newer `awk` should be the first try...

Comment: Is it possible to add in the last row the TOTAL sum for every column?

Comment: in addition can we sort the first column? and can we remove all rows that have as difference value 0?

Comment: the version with line for "total", sorting and skipping lines without difference worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: You have example input files for me showing 0-differences?

Comment: the version with line for "total", sorting and skipping lines without difference worked perfectly! Thank you! It was my mistake I added a ; between the for loop and the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '
FNR==NR {
    a[$1] = $2;
    c[$1] = $1;
    next;
}
{
    b[$1] = $2;
    c[$1] = $1;
}   
END {
    printf "type\tvalue1\tvalue2\tdifference\n";
    for(i in c)
        printf "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, a[i], b[i], a[i]-b[i]
}' file1 file2
type    value1  value2  difference
remark  2       240     -238
test    27      0       27
viewer  23      2990    -2967
exam    0       200     -200
```

Comment: hi Gnouc, when running your command I had the Column value1 all equal to 0.

Comment: Are you sure you type the command correctly?

Comment: yes I'm sure I did. bash$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1] = $2;c[$1] = $1;next;}{b[$1] = $2;c[$1] = $1;} END {printf "TABLE\tREF\tHEAD\tdifference\n"; for(i in c) printf "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, a[i], b[i], a[i]-b[i]}' file1 file2
TABLE   REF     HEAD    difference
viewer  0       2990    -2990
exam    0       200     -200
remark  0       240     -240
test    0       27      -27

Comment: Please check your input file, remove all blank line. Here is my result when running above command:http://pastebin.com/ugxK6R5E

Comment: Even on Linux it is not working.

Comment: Can you paste your terminal output somewhere

Comment: nawk solved the issue as proposed by yeti. thank you!